# Can a Static library (.a) compiled in mac OS work in linux?

Tags: static, linker, archive

Can a static library (.a) compiled in Mac OS work in Linux? Do archives in Mac OS and Linux have the same format?

Answer (score 2):

> Can a static library (.a) compiled in Mac OS work in Linux?

Yes, but only if you use [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) to compile object files that you'll put into that library.

> Do archives in Mac OS and Linux have the same format?

It is very likely that the format of `.a` [archive files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) is the same between Linux and Mac OSX (I have not verified this, but most UNIX systems use the format referenced above), but that isn't going to help you: the archive library is little more than a concatenation of `.o` files with some indices, and `.o` files themselves are different between Linux ([ELF object file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)) and Mac OSX ([Mach-O object file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O)).

The Linux linker will have no trouble looking inside the `.a`, but it will ignore any non-ELF files it finds there.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that different OSs have different syscalls and low-level OS functions (which even if you don't use them directly, may appear in the object file through macros and/or inlining) and different ways to call them, so even if you convert a Mach-O file to ELF, it isn't likely to work on Linux.

Comment: It should *also* be pointed out that there are Linuxes for different CPU architectures, so even if everything else matched, who is to say they're even compiled for the same architecture.

Comment: @sepp2k Not to mention the higher-level functions are generally totally different.

Answer (score 0):

*Which* Linux? Linux is compiled for many CPU architectures. Macs are currently x86-only.

As others mentioned, Macs use the Mach-O executable format, while Linuxes usually use ELF, and the way syscalls are handled and which libraries are available are completely different.

So in practice, on out-of-the-box systems, there may be similarities, but it's unlikely anything will run.

Question is: What are you trying to do?

There are ways (like http://www.darlinghq.org) to make executables from one platform run on the other, by adding code that performs an on-the-fly translation and implementing the missing libraries.

There may also be a way to create a .a file that contains executables for several platforms, so compilers will pick the right one and ignore the other. If you used a cross-compiler, you could probably build a `.a` on a Mac that contains code compiled for a Linux.

Comment: We are talking here about a x86-linux.

Comment: If you limit the answer to the x86 CPU architecture, then You gain the advantage that at least the CPU architecture is the same as on macOS. That still doesn't fix the discrepancies in ABI, like syscalls, nor in packaging.